# Is it possible to increase the height of the text boxes in a Smart Capture Form in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, css, html, smart-capture

I want to increase the height of the text box in a Smart Capture Form. I simply increased the height using CSS and it shows the big box. However when I publish the page and click on the url, it doesn't show the larger box, just the original one. Am I going about this in the wrong way? And if so, is there something else that would work to fix the box size like I want?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: It can take up to 5mins to publish pages, are you sure you are looking at the published version? Sometimes what I do is add a bit of text at the top so I can identify if its the newer published version that's displaying or the older version

Comment: Yeah, I even changed the text size and color and that change showed on the published page but the box was still small